# Alternatives for checking if something is not None in Python

Tags: python-3.x, functional-programming

I recently bumped into [dry-python/returns](https://github.com/dry-python/returns), which seems like a very useful project. In the project description, the authors describe a snippet which can be written with their `Maybe` container in a better way (according to the authors):

The original code is:

```
if user is not None:
     balance = user.get_balance()
     if balance is not None:
         credit = balance.credit_amount()
         if credit is not None and credit > 0:
             discount_program = choose_discount(credit)
```

And the improved version is:

```
discount_program: Maybe['DiscountProgram'] = Maybe.from_optional(
    user,
).bind_optional(  
    lambda real_user: real_user.get_balance(),
).bind_optional(
    lambda balance: balance.credit_amount(),
).bind_optional(
    lambda credit: choose_discount(credit) if credit > 0 else None,
)
```

This is a legitimate solution. However, I would write the first code as:

```
if user:
   balance = user.get_balance()
   if balance:
      credit = balance.credit_amount()
      if credit > 0:
          discount_program = choose_discount(credit)
```

Being a long time pylint user that the style that is recommended.
Honestly, I've never given it much thought, and now that I saw the first
code, I started asking myself if I should give it some thought.

The most dangerous place IMHO, in my version is:

```
if credit > 0:
```

Since `None` will raise here a `TypeError`. However, the original line can be written as:

```
if credit and credit > 0:
   discount_program = choose_discount(credit)
```

My favorite style for re-writing this block would be very LISPy. I use `getattr` with a default value which is callable (a lambda which returns None). This very similar to what the example in return does, but without a 3rd party library:

```
choose_discount(
   getattr(
      getattr(user, 'get_balance', lambda: None)(),
      'credit_amount', lambda: 0)())
```

Which I think would not be like by many because it's very unusual. Also, for this to work properly, I would write `choose_discount` as:

```
def  choose_discount(credit):
    if credit:
        return "Your discount choosing ..."
    else:
        return "No discount"
```

If allowed to use a newer version of Python, I would probably use the walrus operator here:

```
if (credit := getattr(getattr(user, 'get_balance', lambda: None)(), 'credit_amount', lambda: 0)()) > 0:
    discount_program = choose_discount(credit)
```

This style strongly assume that `credit_amount` always returns a type which can be numerically compared ... Hence, the caveat I mentioned earlier, with credit being a None is implicitly handled.

I have a few questions regarding this.

- Can you point out possible caveats in my style?
- Could I be missing out something terrible, and I should look for `is not None`
  explicitly?
- Is the functional style legitimate here or should I absolutely avoid it?

Comment: Unfortunately this question has been closed just before I could submit my answer. Don't do `if variable` unless `variable` is of type `bool`. It's easy to accidentally discard valid values this way, e.g. if `variable` is `0`. There is no other way to test if `variable` is not `None` than `if variable is not None`. However, the example given is not good python anyway because a) they return `None` where an exception should have been raised instead and b) it is "LBYL" style whereas in python the "EAFP" style is usually preferred.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I felt like the problem solved was not a problem at all because of EAFP. Seemed weired for me that so many functions should return `None`... As for `if variable` should be a boolean, that is a good thing to take from this discussion.

Answer (score 2):

I thought the readme on [dry-python/return](https://github.com/dry-python/returns) did a good job of explaining the usage of the `Maybe` type.

The key to understanding `Maybe` is that it *represents computations which might "go wrong" by not returning a value.*

The `bind` method (`bind_optional`) in this library allows you to write code without having to worry about the result of the computation at any intermediate step, it handles the case where one of the computations returns None.

In the code you use to demonstrate the conditionals, you still have to handle the cases of `None` via an `if` statement, the use of `if not None` vs `if Some` isn't relevant. As a hypothetical consider a computation with many level of `optional` results from computation, you'd still have to implement the same level of nesting.

In the example from the documentation

```py
user: Optional[User]

# Type hint here is optional, it only helps the reader here:
discount_program: Maybe['DiscountProgram'] = Maybe.from_optional(
    user,
).bind_optional(  # This won't be called if `user is None`
    lambda real_user: real_user.get_balance(),
).bind_optional(  # This won't be called if `real_user.get_balance()` is None
    lambda balance: balance.credit_amount(),
).bind_optional(  # And so on!
    lambda credit: choose_discount(credit) if credit > 0 else None,
)
```

the comments in the code say the same. You can imagine a library using a symbolic function name `>>=` with `infix` operators allowing the above code to be rewritten as

```py
credit = user >>= (lambda real_user: real_user.get_balance())
              >>= (lambda balance: balance.credit_amount()) 
              >>= (lambda credit: choose_discount(credit) if credit > 0 else None)
```

IMO, you approach to utilizing `getattr` is more akin to programming in a "[duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)" style than functional.

I used the haskell wiki's description of the [`Maybe` monad](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_monads/Maybe) if you want to dig in further.